# Creating Text Elements using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, layouts

From what I can tell python at ArcGIS Desktop 10.0 **cannot** create new [textElements](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/TextElement/00s30000000m000000/) nor [GraphicElements](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s300000040000000). Yet, 10.1 seems to support the ability to at least create a clone, of a existing [GraphicElements](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000040000000), but not create one from scratch.

Can someone confirm this?

Does anyone know of any workaround to create a textElement from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true.

ArcPy at ArcGIS Desktop 10.0 cannot create or copy/clone graphic or text elements using the arcpy.mapping module.

ArcPy from ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop has a clone option is available, but it is still not possible to create a graphic or text element from scratch.

This software behaviour is the same in ArcPy from ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop where the [TextElement (arcpy.mapping) help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s30000000m000000) says:

> The TextElement object provides access to properties that enable its
>   repositioning on the page layout as well as modifying the text string
>   and font size.
>
> ...
>
> Existing text elements can be cloned and deleted. This capability was
>   initially added to support the creation of dynamic graphic tables. To
>   accomplish this, a map document must be authored with the text
>   elements having the appropriate symbology.