# Changing draw text element to be right to left using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, data-driven-pages, dynamic-tables, unicodedecodeerror

I'm trying to produce a set of maps in certain locations using Data Driven Pages. I'm using a script written in python that generates a dynamic table in each sheet. The table has attributes of all the entities participating in that particular sheet.

The dynamic table is been generated just fine expect I want the attribute to be written in *right to left* writing instead of default *left to right*.

**How to generate text element that is written in *right to left*?**

The function needs to be as in the label's editor option:[image: The Arcmap GUI].

This question was asked in different variation as [Understanding UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec in ArcPy script?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147605/understanding-unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-in-arcpy-script) here and pretty much the same in [GeoNet](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/133884). It didn't get any useful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you will see in [Creating Text Elements using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28888/does-arcmap-arcpy-support-creation-of-textelements-using-python) it is not possible to generate/create a text element in any form using ArcPy.

However, what you can do is to:

1. use ArcMap to insert a text element into your layout and then configure it as `Right to left`
2. use ArcPy to either use that text element (if you only need one) or clone it if you need more.